# Passing Json object from angular to springboot in POST method

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot

I am new to Full stack development with Angular and Springboot.
I am trying to implement Cart functionality for my app.

My Spring boot controller is :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("cart")
@Slf4j
public class CartController {

    @Autowired
    ICartService cartService;
    
    @ApiOperation(value = "To add item to cart on with Book id and quantity from user")
    @PostMapping("/addToCart/{token}")
    public ResponseEntity<Response> addBookToCart(@PathVariable String token,@RequestBody CartDTO cartDto) {
        log.info("Cart dto: " + cartDto);
        Response response = cartService.addToCart(token,cartDto);
        return new ResponseEntity<Response>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

And my CartDTO.java is:

```
public @Data class CartDTO {

    private long bookId;
    
    private int quantity;
}
```

In Angular, this is what my Cart Service looks it :

```
export class CartService {

   headeroption = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
  };
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { 
  }


  public addToCart(id:any) {
  
    let cartObj = {
      "bookId" : id,
      "quantity" : 2
    }
    var token = localStorage.getItem("ACCESS_TOKEN")
    
    return this.http.post("http://localhost:8080/cart/addToCart/"+token,cartObj,this.headeroption)
  }
}
```

But on executing **public addToCart(id:any)** method, in spring controller I am getting response with value as '0' :

```
Cart dto: CartDTO(bookId=0, quantity=0)
```

Can some tell me why I am not getting the required data in my controller?

Comment: I guess you need to convert them into a POJO type from the API call.

Comment: Could you please suggest how can I do that?

Comment: Refer this: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-resttemplate-post-json

Comment: @GnanaJeyam Yes I am able to use it within springboot, but as mentioned in my question I want to know how to map between angular and spring

Comment: Are you able to see the response from postman, If so you need to do some changes in your Angular http client. Can you update the frontend service code also.. ?

Comment: Yes the response is proper in postman. I have added my angular cart service code above.

Comment: Instead of directly returning the `http.post` try to convert the response to model.

Comment: Yes I even tried with creating a DTO in angular and then send it to spring. But still I am getting same issue.

Comment: could you share your code in github link..?

Comment: Which one angular or springboot? Since I have two separate git links for them